# Как заставить работать промежуток в For на bash?

Tags: bash, sh

Появилась нужда написать простой bash скрипт, в цикле от 1 до Х выполняющий определённый код, но так:

```
#!/bin/bash
for c in {1...5}
do
#some code
done
```

не работает, и так:

```
...
for (( i=1 ; i < 5 ; i++ )) 
...
```

тоже. Что делать? Bash версии 4.4-5 .

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 4); do echo $i; done`

Comment: В первом варианте должно быть две точки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
for num in 1 2 3 5 7 11 ; do echo $num ; done
```

или так:

```
for num in $(seq 1 10) ; do echo $num ; done
```

UPD:

В сценарии можно сделать так:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then echo "to few args" && return 1;
else
  for num in $(seq 1 $1) ; do echo $num ; done        
fi
```

а затем вызывать:

```
./script.sh 5
>>> 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: 2-й вариант подошёл, спасибо.

Comment: @АлексКетчер, вариант добавил в UPD в ответ.